# Checboxes input helper PodsCms

Tags: wordpress, helper, podscms

i created a multiple checkboxes input helper adapting the code from this http://podscms.org/packages/checkboxradiobutton-yourvalues/

I modified it so that people don't have to hardcode values into the helper; instead values are taken from the column comment field (having a data field for columns would be appreciated in pods 2.0!)

Here is the helper: http://pastebin.com/w0UxDmnG

I encountered two problems, the first of which i already solved:

1. At thw beginning i enclosed the whole code in a function, to keep clean the namespace (isn'i it the right thing to do?). but i noticed that i do this, when i have two columns with this helper many strange things happen: the second column is blank, doesn't show checkboxes. After the second column with this helper no more columns are shown.Rich editor commands on all textareas don't appear and textareas themselves are non editable.
   I suppose is an effect wrapping the code in a function. Unwrapped the code, problems are gone! (i wrote this because it can be helpful to developers out there.
2. I wanted to add a "Other" text field for comments outside the choices displayed with checboxes (like in google forms, for example). To trigger this "other" ("Altro" in the package i shared), pod creators have to write [] in the comments (eg: foo, bar, cat, []). 
   I was able to make the input, but, once data is filled in and the pods is saved, the data in the text field get lost. I really have no idea on how to fix this!

I hope my experience, and this helper could help someone, and i hope some could help me to improve it!

(and please someone create a podscms tag!!)

Answer (score 0):

Pods 2.0 solves this kind of issue, it's now built into core as a field type option. Enjoy!